# Loch Ness monster and Jacob's Ladder Surfaces are NOT homeomorphic

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, alternative-proof, surfaces, riemann-surfaces

[image]

I am looking for proof of the fact that $X($Jacob's Ladder surface$)$ is not homeomorphic to $Y($Loch Ness monster surface$)$. Certainly, fundamentals groups do not help as the fundamental groups of both spaces are free groups of countably many generators$($both $X,Y$ are homotopically equivalent to wedge of countably many circles$).$ Similarly, homology groups $H_0=\Bbb Z,H_1=\prod_{\text{countable}}\Bbb Z, H_2=0, H_n=0$ for all $n\geq 3$ in either cases.

Now, Ian Richard's classification of non-compact surfaces can be used to distinguish these spaces, looking at the number of ends. But I am looking for an alternative proof, if possible.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean alternative proof? Would cutting along a separating simple closed curve count as an "ends proof"(one will have two infinite genus components, the other will only have one)?

Comment: This question appears in a lecture note on algebraic topology without any topic on the classification theory of non-compact surfaces just after the basic result of fundamental groups, but it contains the classification theory of all compact surfaces. That's why I believe that using basic tools of algebraic topology one can distinguish these two spaces.

Comment: Cut $X$ between two tori, i.e., along a $S^1$ into two parts. The closures of the parts re not compact. Do the same with the supposed image of the $S^1$ in $Y$. As this image of $S^1$ is compact, one of the two parts of $Y$ must be bounded, hence its closure compact. Contardiction.

Comment: If they were homeomorphic, then the "end loop" of Loch Ness would map to an "end loop" of Jacob's Ladder. But Jacob's Ladder doesn't have an end loop. This is just a guess btw, as I know next to nothing about Topology.

Comment: @Sumanta The classification of surfaces is different from being able to distinguish two "explicit" surfaces. Without more context it would be hard to say what is "expected". I wouldn't expect a simple/basic algebraic topology proof that doesn't essentially boil down to the ends invariant

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen could you tell me why it is necessary that a separating loop in $X$, as mentioned by you, goes to a (special and same type of) separating loop in $Y$ under any homomorphism if any?

Comment: By the way, $H_2$ of both surfaces are trivial, since both spaces are noncompact.  Further, I believe $X$ and $Y$ both deformation retract to a countabl wedge of circles.  In particular  I think $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Each noncompact connected surface is h.e. to a wedge of circles.  So yes, these two surfaces are homotopy-equivalent, but not properly homotopy equivalent.

Comment: @Jason DeVito. Thanks, I forgotten the result that $H_2=\Bbb Z$ if and only if surface is closed and orientable, otherwise $H_2=0$.

Comment: You should specify what tools of algebraic topology you know (besides homology and cohomology). For instance, do you know about compactly-supported cohomology groups?

Comment: I think there are 3 loop in $Y$ such that if we remove them the result is 3 connected component 2 of them bounded but  I couldn't find such separation for $X$.

Comment: @Sumanta: To answer your comment directed at HagenvonEitzen, if $f : X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism and $C \subset X$ is a subset, then $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism from $C$ to $f(C)$, from $X-C$ to $Y-f(C)$, and from $\overline{X-C}$ to $\overline{Y-f(C)}$. So if $\overline{X-C}$ has two components each noncompact, then $\overline{Y-f(C)}$ must have two components each noncompact. So if $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic, and $X$ has the property of possessing a loop with two complementary components each having noncompact closure, then $Y$ has that same property.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Is the HagenvonEitzen's argument correct? But we can choose a tori like figure (d) in my post.

Comment: Suppose the loops $C \subset X$ and $f(C) \subset Y$ had the properties that you said. As said in my comment, $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism from $X-C$ to $Y-f(C)$. You can now use this homeomorphism to contradict those properties that you said.

Comment: @LeeMosher: If we remove a circle it is equivalent to removing a disk of both. Now your argument says that these two cannot be homeomorphic but this is same as original question.

Comment: @Lee Mosher I completely understand your first comment, no doubt towards your first comment. It is actually what I am looking for. As you can see from my first comment that the question appears just after introducing fundamental group in a lecture note on Algebraic Topology.

Comment: This sentence makes little sense: "If we remove a circle it is equivalent to removing a disc of both". There is not any way in which cutting $X$ along the $S^1$ suggested by @HagenvonEitzen is "equivalent to removing a disc". Perhaps you do not understand what $S^1$ it is suggested be removed?

Comment: @LeeMosher: Remove the right side single tori of figure (d) below. and remove the left side tori of $Y$ in the OP question. Isn't the result same as each other?

Comment: Now look at the result. Both of the results can be obtained by removing a disk of original manifolds. Isn't?

Comment: The suggestion of @HagenvonEitzen is not to remove a torus or any other 2-dimensional submanifold. The suggestion is instead to remove from $X$ an $S^1$, meaning a submanifold that is homeomorphic to the unit circle. Specifically, remove an $S^1$ "between two tori", which cuts $X$ into two pieces. Removal of that $S^1$ leaves a subset with two pieces, i.e. two connected components, and each of those pieces has noncompact closure in $X$.

Comment: Let me explain again. (Maybe I'm wrong). Cut the right side single tori of figure (d) below. now we have a bounded and an unbounded subset (two connected components). OK? Now cut the left side tori of Y in the OP question. again we have a bounded and an unbounded subset (two connected components).

Comment: By "Both of the results can be obtained by removing a disk of original manifolds" I meant those unbounded components can be constructed by removing a disk of original manifolds.

Comment: @Sumanta: Can you explain what is your idea for this problem using general topology? (in regard to your [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816300#comment7871931_3816300) and [this comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816300#comment7871678_3816300).)

Comment: @Sumanta: No. I want to know about proving using general topology tools what you told in above comment [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816300#comment7871931_3816300) and [this comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816300#comment7871678_3816300).)

Comment: @Sumanta: Specially this part: *it is now easy to solve the above problem using tools of general topology*

Comment: @Sumanta: So, By this how you can prove the assertion that X and Y are not homeomorphic?

Comment: No, You cannot tell this strongly. This is exactly same as the original problem. I.e. you are using the theorem itself. How you can guarantee that there is no loop in Y that separate it in two unbounded components?

Comment: No, You meant we can find a loop in Y that separates it in two components one bounded and other unbounded? If so, There is such loop in X too.

Comment: I can find similar $S_{g,1}$ in X such that $X\backslash S_{g,1}$ is connected.

Comment: I know that. my example is similar to your with one boundary. (my previous comment (deleted) was about complement of that i.e. $Y\backslash S_{g,1}$)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will start with some very general remarks about proper homotopy invariants.

Let $X$ be a connected manifold (one needs much less). Consider an exhaustion of $X$ by compact submanifolds with boundary $K_i$:
$$
X= \bigcup_i K_i, K_i\subset int(K_{i+1})~~ \forall i. 
$$
Every such exhaustion defines a direct system of maps of cohomology groups
$$
H^*(X, X-K_i) \to H^*(X, X-K_j), i\le j. 
$$
The direct limit of this system is denoted $H_c^*(X)$, the compactly supported cohomology of $X$; it is independent of the exhaustion. Feeding the relative cohomology groups and their maps as above into long exact sequence of pairs $(X, X-K_i)$ we get a commutative diagram:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
\to& \tilde{H}^{k-1}(X) & \to & \tilde{H}^{k-1}(X - K_i) & \to & H^k(X, X-K_i) & \to & \tilde{H}^{k+1}(X) & \to\\
    & \downarrow & & \downarrow & &\downarrow& &\downarrow& \\
\to& \tilde{H}^{k-1}(X) & \to & \tilde{H}^{k-1}(X - K_j) & \to & H^k(X, X-K_j) & \to & \tilde{H}^{k+1}(X) & \to
\end{array} 
$$
Taking the direct limit we obtain a long exact sequence
$$
... \to \tilde{H}^{k-1}(X)  \to  \tilde{H}^{k-1}_\epsilon(X)  \to  H_c^k(X)  \to \tilde{H}^{k+1}(X)  \to ...
$$
The groups $\tilde{H}^{*}_\epsilon(X)$ are again independent of the exhaustion, they are direct limits of the systems
$$
\tilde{H}^*(X-K_i) \to \tilde{H}^*(X-K_j), i\le j. 
$$
(You can see that they are independent of the exhaustion either by appealing to the independence of compactly supported cohomology groups or by repeating the same argument you use for $H^*_c$.)

**Remark.** This is actually quite general: If $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ is a direct system of groups (or, more generally, objects in some category) and $(G_i)_{i\in J}$ is a subsystem given by a cofinal subset $J\subset I$, then we get a natural isomorphism
$$
\lim_{i\in J} G_i\cong \lim_{i\in I} G_i. 
$$
In our setting, $I$ will be the poset of all compact subsets of $X$ and $J\subset I$ will be a subset of $I$ given by a particular exhaustion $(K_i)$. The assumption that $(K_i)$ is an exhaustion implies that $J$ is cofinal in $I$.

**Definition.** The groups $\tilde{H}^*_\epsilon(X)$ are the reduced *end-cohomology groups* of $X$.

**Remark.** In fact, I did not need the compactly supported cohomology groups, I just wanted to relate the end-cohomology to something you already know.

Independence of the exhaustion implies that these groups are topological invariants of $X$; they are also invariants of proper homotopy type of $X$: Each proper homotopy-equivalence $X\to Y$ induces isomorphisms
$$
H^*_c(Y)\to H^*_c(X), H^*_\epsilon(Y)\to H^*_\epsilon(X).  
$$

Now, back to your question. Take your surface $X$ and exhaust it by compact subsurfaces $K_i$ such that $X-K_i$ consists of two unbounded components. For $Y$, exhaust by compact subsurfaces $L_i$ each of which has connected (unbounded) complement. Computing the end-cohomology we get
$$
\tilde{H}^0_\epsilon(X)= {\mathbb Z}, \tilde{H}^0_\epsilon(Y)=0 
$$
since for each pair $j\ge i$ we get isomorphisms
$$
{\mathbb Z}=\tilde{H}^0(X-K_i) \to \tilde{H}^0(X-K_j)= {\mathbb Z}, 
$$
$$
0=\tilde{H}^0(Y-L_i) \to \tilde{H}^0(Y-L_j)= 0. 
$$
Hence, $X$ is not homeomorphic to $Y$. The same proof shows that these surfaces are not properly homotopy-equivalent.

Lastly, even though you did not ask about it, using Richards' classification of surfaces one can prove even more:

**Theorem.** Two surfaces are properly homotopy-equivalent if and only if they are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 4):

**Non-Answer:** Here is some figures that would be helpful.

- An easy observation but interesting for me: One can find a loop that after removing it the bounded component of both are homeomorphic to torus minus open disk: figures (a) and (d). So removing one loop trick does not work.
- Unfortunately removing 3 loops also does not work. one can do same process (b-c-d) to (d) and construct bounded components like (a).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**This is not my own answer. I have stolen this argument from Lee Mosher's comment. There is already a full and good solution provided by Moishe Kohan. In case you lost in the comments and still want an alternative solution, you may read below.**

If $f:X→Y$ is a homeomorphism and $C\subseteq X$ is a subset, then $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism from $C$ to $f(C)$, from $X−C$ to $Y−f(C)$, and from $\overline{X−C}$ to $\overline{Y−f(C)}$. So if $X−C$ has two components each noncompact, then $Y−f(C)$ must have two components each noncompact. So if $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic, and $X$ has the property of possessing a loop with two complementary components each having noncompact closure, then $Y$ has that same property.

We can find an embedding $ψ:\Bbb S^1↪X$ such that $X−\text{im } ψ$ has two components each having non-compact closures, but if $Y$ were homeomorphic to $X$, then $Y$ would also have the same property, but, removing any loop form $Y$ we have exactly one component with non-compact closure.

*But, why removing any loop form $Y$ we have exactly one component with non-compact closure? We can proceed as follows.*

Let $S_{g,1}$ be an embedded compact submanifold of $Y$ having $g$-genus and **one boundary component**. Let $γ:\Bbb S^1↪Y$ be an embedded loop in $Y$ contained in the interior of some $S_{g,1}$. Now, $Y\backslash S_{g,1}⊆Y\backslash γ$, and $Y\backslash S_{g,1}$ is connected, so $Y\backslash S_{g,1}$ is contained in one component of $Y\backslash γ$. That is to say all other components of $Y\backslash γ$, if exist, must be inside in $S_{g,1}$ and thus bounded.