# Quasi-isometry between an once-punctured torus and the Loch Ness Monster under suitable metrics

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, geometric-topology, metric-geometry

I was wondering if there are quasi-isometric (complete) metrics on the once-punctured torus and the [Loch Ness Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_Ness_monster_surface). By an once-punctured torus I mean the 1-genus surface with one puncture and by the Loch Ness Monster I mean the orientable surface of infinite genus with an unique *end* (see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350478/end-space-of-non-compact-2-manifolds-in-terms-of-proper-rays) of mine for concrete definitions) which is necessarily non-planar.

For instance, the once-punctured torus admits a hyperbolic metric for which the puncture is identified with a hyperbolic cusp isometric to the product $S^1\times [1,+\infty)$, where $S^1$ is the circle equipped with a flat metric $dx$ and the metric on the product is given by the Riemannian metric
$$\frac{dx^2+dt^2}{t^2}.$$

Thus, according to Sam Nead's answer on [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73219/hyperbolicity-on-riemann-surfaces), the once-punctured torus is quasi-isometric to a ray.

On the other hand, thinking on the end space of the Loch Ness Monster in terms of proper rays (See my previously cited post for a concrete description), I would be tempted to suppose that the Loch Ness Monster carries a metric for which a geodesic ray escaping to its unique end makes the surface quasi-isometric to a ray as well, in analogy with the once-punctured torus and the geodesic rays escaping to its hyperbolic cusp.

In case that my question had a negative answer, at least can we find a metric in the infinitely non-orientable surface of infinite genus with an unique end (which is necessarily non-orientable) quasi-isometric to either of the two surfaces above under suitable (complete) metrics?.

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct provided one uses a suitable hyperbolic metric on  the Loch Ness Monster (for *some* hyperbolic metrics this will fail). Namely, you want the "handles" of the monster in the picture [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816300/loch-ness-monster-and-jacobs-ladder-surfaces-are-not-homeomorphic/3816563) to be roughly of the same size.